# Web Scraping with Java/Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract average salary from GlassDoor.
This is the HTML code where it is:

```
<span class="OccMedianBasePayStyle__payNumber" data-test="AveragePay">$118,034</span>
```

Here is what I have so far..
This code outputs the line I want but I don't know how to just pull out the salary from data-test="AveragePay"

```
public class Trans {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/seattle-software-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,7_IM781_KO8,25.htm";
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //a with href
        Elements links = document.select("span");

        for (Element link : links) {

            System.out.println("Text: " + link.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("data-test", "Average"));

            //System.out.println("Text: " + link.text()); 
        }
```

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: My output is just pumping out values and I don't know how to pinpoint the one I want.      I would like to be able to output the value for "data-test="AveragePay"

Comment: I started web scraping yesterday so I'm probably going about this the wrong way. I just don't know how to extract data from the specific spots I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct selector. you should pass data-test="AveragePay" with the span.

Change your selector and for loop to this, its basically selecting elements only which has span[data-test="AveragePay"]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Salaries/seattle-software-engineer-salary-SRCH_IL.0,7_IM781_KO8,25.htm";
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //a with href
        Elements links = document.select("span[data-test='AveragePay']");

        for (Element link : links) {                
            System.out.println("Text: " + link.text());     
        }
 }
```

Note: I hope this is only for educational purpose. Web Scraping has some legal restrictions. You need to check the terms and conditions of the target site, before using this for any commercial purpose.

Comment: When I try that, nothing is outputted. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: I am not sure. I tried the same code with the link and its working fine. I am pasting the complete code.

Comment: I got it to work, I had to take off the ' symbol surrounding AveragePay